# Use AngularJS app as a bower package

Tags: angularjs, bower

I've made my own AngularJS app, which works as an independant project.
What i want to do is use this app in another project. I made it a bower package and added it as a dependecy on my project, but i've no idea how to initialize it. As an independant App it used to work through its own URL.

Any tips?

Comment: If you provide code snippet. What have you achieved so far, then only we can help.

Comment: Is a complete app, a module a directive. We need some infos

Comment: i'm not sure what code I could show you tbh. 

@rick it's a module in fact.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a module you after you imported the js oyu can addit to your new module dependencies

```
newApp= angular.module('newApp', ['comparatorApp']);
```

Comment: The project i want to use it in is not using angularJs though.